# What is the difference between 'DependsOnTargets' and 'AfterTargets'?

Tags: msbuild

What is the difference between `DependsOnTargets` and `AfterTargets`?
I can not distinguish these two.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

### DependsOnTargets

Defines the targets that **must be executed before** the target can be executed.

```
<Target Name="DependsOn" DependsOnTargets="DependencyTarget1;DependencyTarget2">
  <Message Text="Target : DependsOn"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="DependencyTarget2">
  <Message Text="Target : DependencyTarget2"/>
</Target> 

<Target Name="DependencyTarget1">
  <Message Text="Target : DependencyTarget1"/>
</Target> 

Output
> Target : DependencyTarget1
> Target : DependencyTarget2
> Target : DependsOn
```

### BeforeTargets and AfterTargets (Only available in MSBuild 4)

Indicates that the target should **run** before or after the specified target or targets.

```
<Target Name="BeforeAndAfter">
  <Message Text="Target : BeforeAndAfter"/>
</Target>

<!-- BeforeTarget1 will run BEFORE target "BeforeAndAfter" -->
<Target Name="BeforeTarget" BeforeTargets="BeforeAndAfter">
  <Message Text="BeforeTarget run before : BeforeAndAfter"/>
</Target> 

<!-- BeforeTarget1 will run AFTER target "BeforeAndAfter" -->
<Target Name="AfterTarget" AfterTargets="BeforeAndAfter">
  <Message Text="AfterTarget run after : BeforeAndAfter"/>
</Target> 

Output
> BeforeTarget run before : BeforeAndAfter
> Target : BeforeAndAfter
> AfterTarget run after : BeforeAndAfter
```

- If you have multiples targets that should run before or after the same specified target, they will be **executed in declaration order** :

  ```
  <Target Name="BeforeAndAfter">
    <Message Text="Target : BeforeAndAfter"/>
  </Target>

  <!-- 
     BOTH BeforeTarget1 and BeforeTarget2 should run before target "BeforeAndAfter"
  -->
  <Target Name="BeforeTarget1" BeforeTargets="BeforeAndAfter">
    <Message Text="BeforeTarget1 run before : BeforeAndAfter"/>
  </Target> 

  <Target Name="BeforeTarget2" BeforeTargets="BeforeAndAfter">
    <Message Text="BeforeTarget2 run before : BeforeAndAfter"/>
  </Target>
  ```

`BeforeTargets` and `AfterTargets` could be use to **extend existing build process**.

For example, with this attributes you can easily execute a target before **CoreCompile** (*defines in Microsoft.CSharp.targets*). Without that you'll have to override the property `CoreCompileDependsOn`.

Without `AfterTargets` you have no way to easily execute a target after another one if no extension point is defined (`CallTarget` at the end of the target with a property that you can override)

### DependsOnTargets, BeforeTargets and AfterTargets execution order?

When `DependsOnTargets`, `BeforeTargets` and `AfterTargets` are used on the same target, the order of execution is :

- `DependsOnTargets`
- `BeforeTargets`
- The target
- `AfterTargets`

  ```
  <Target Name="MainTarget" DependsOnTargets="DefaultDependsOn">
    <Message Text="Target : MainTarget"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="DefaultDependsOn">
    <Message Text="Target : DefaultDependsOn"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="DefaultBeforeTarget" BeforeTargets="MainTarget">
    <Message Text="Target : DefaultBeforeTarget"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="DefaultAfterTarget" AfterTargets="MainTarget">
    <Message Text="Target : DefaultAfterTarget"/>
  </Target> 

  Output
  > Target : DefaultDependsOn
  > Target : DefaultBeforeTarget
  > Target : MainTarget
  > Target : DefaultAfterTarget
  ```

Comment: I think you got the order of execution wrong; it should be `AfterTargets -> The target -> BeforeTargets`.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is the top-rated. It does not explain the difference in behavior between AfterTargets and DependsOnTargets. [aprelev's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855713/what-is-the-difference-between-dependsontargets-and-aftertargets#comment83741182_34099077) actually answers it.

Answer (score 25):

More succinctly [from this GitHub issue on Microsoft Docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/2994):

`<Target Name="x" DependsOnTargets="y" />` means:

If something wants to run `x`, `y` must run first.

`<Target Name="a" AfterTargets="b" />` means:

If something runs `b`, then run `a` after it.

Answer (score 12):

While the other answers previously provided are correct, I think they failed to mention what I think is the primary benefit of `AfterTargets` over `DependsOnTargets`.

`DependsOnTargets` has been around from the beginning of MSBuild. The problem with `DependsOnTargets`, is that it requires a target author to explicitly allow for extensibility. This is done by defining a property that is used as the `DependsOnTargets` value, as follows:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <SomeTargetDependsOnTargets>
     Dependency1;Dependency2
   </SomeTargetDependsOnTargets>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="SomeTarget" DependsOnTargets="$(SomeTargetDependsOnTargets)">
 ...
</Target>
```

You could then add a dependency by modifying the `SomeTargetDependsOnTargets` property as follows:

```
<SomeTargetDependsOnTargets>
    $(SomeTargetDependsOnTargets);Dependency3
</SomeTargetDependsOnTargets>
```

The problem with this design, is that if the author had simply inlined `Dependency1;Dependency2` rather than extracting it into a property, there would be no way to externally modify it to allow for customization.

`AfterTargets`, on the other hand, doesn't require the original target author to have explicitly extracted the `DependsOnTargets` value into a property to allow for extensibility.

Comment: I think your response correctly answers the question. Not sure why an explanation of what these mean has been marked as the answer. In any case, your answer did help me understand the difference. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I think the answer is much simpler.  The effect of `DependsOnTargets` and `AfterTargets` is essentially the same.  The reason for `BeforeTargets` & `AfterTargets` (from the Microsoft Documentation):

> This lets the project author extend an existing set of targets without
>   modifying them directly.

So if you have an existing target B and you want to add a new target A that must execute first, you have two choices:

1. Modify target B to read: `DependsOnTargets="A"`.
2. Modify target A to read: `BeforeTargets="B"`.

If you can't modify B (e.g. it's an existing Microsoft target), that's when you need `BeforeTargets`.

Comment: @Steve Robbins Commenting on your second statement, *no, they are not the same*. There is a peculiar twist to this, which everybody else failed to mention: consider building target A as in `msbuild /t:A`. 
When dependency is specified with `DependsOnTargets` attribute, invoking msbuild in such manner *does not build target B*. 
However, when dependency is specified with `AfterTargets` attribute, invoking msbuild in such manner *does build target B*.

Comment: @aprelev: OK, fair enough.  In my defence: I did say "essentially" :-)   I was thinking only of the dependency chain, assuming the initial target would be "B" or something that depends on it.  Thanks for pointing out this subtlety.

Comment: Thanks @aprelev, your comment is the only useful thing I find in this entire page. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

One more difference, that is mentioned in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48381305/6537984) is that

> `BeforeTargets` and `AfterTargets` are run regardless of the Condition whereas `DependsOnTargets` (and target itself) are skipped when Condition evaluates to false"

1. In below code second target is executed even though first target is not executed:

   ```
   <Target Name="FirstTarget" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'False'">
       <Message Text="This target is never executed" />
   </Target>

   <Target Name="SecondTarget" AfterTargets="FirstTarget">
       <Message Text="SecondTarget is executed" />
   </Target>
   ```
2. In below code second target is not executed:

   ```
   <Target Name="FirstTarget" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'False'">
       <Message Text="This target is never executed" />
   </Target>

   <Target Name="SecondTarget" DependsOnTargets="FirstTarget">
       <Message Text="SecondTarget is executed" />
   </Target>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

One more difference between `AfterTargets` and `DependsOnTargets`.

When you have a target dependency chain/graph, be aware that putting 1+ targets into `BeforeTargets` or `AfterTargets` works like "**any**", and not like "**all**".
It works like saying "if **any** of them has run...", and not "if **all** of them has run..."

Let's say you want to achive this target dependency chain: `A1 -> A2 -> A3`.
The following **will not work:**

```
<Target Name="A1" BeforeTargets="Compile">
    <Message Text="A1" />
</Target>

<Target Name="A3" AfterTargets="A1;A2">
    <Message Text="A3" />
</Target>

<Target Name="A2" AfterTargets="A1">
    <Message Text="A2" />
</Target>
```

Output will be:

```
A1
A3
A2
```

Because, as already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57856955/2080504), the above only means:

```
<Target Name="A1" BeforeTargets="Compile">
```

If `Compile` wants to run, run `A1` before it.

```
<Target Name="A3" AfterTargets="A1;A2">
```

If `A1` run, run `A3` after it.
If `A2` run, run `A3` after it.

```
<Target Name="A2" AfterTargets="A1">
```

If `A1` run, run `A2` after it.

Thus, running `A1` will trigger running `A3`.
Note, that the declaration order matters!

We wanted to say `A3` depends on `A1` and `A2`, but the above did not mean that.

Viewing from another aspect, declaring this:

```
<Target Name="A3" AfterTargets="A1;A2">
```

Works like "if **any** of the AfterTargets has run, run me."
If `A1` or `A2` run, run `A3`

To safely achive target dependency chain `A1 -> A2 -> A3`, I would use `DependsOnTargets` this way:

```
<Target Name="B1" BeforeTargets="Compile">
    <Message Text="B1" />
</Target>

<Target Name="B3" DependsOnTargets="B1;B2" BeforeTargets="Compile">
    <Message Text="B3" />
</Target>

<Target Name="B2" DependsOnTargets="B1" BeforeTargets="Compile">
    <Message Text="B2" />
</Target>
```

Declaring all the dependencies of a Target in `DependsOnTargets` creates the graph/chain we wanted.
Note, that we need to hook in all the targets into the build here in a plus step, because `DependsOnTargets` does not do that (unlike `AfterTargets`). (The above code uses `BeforeTargets="Compile"` in all Targets to achive this)
However, since we declared the dependencies between our Targets, the declaration order (and thus the hook-in order) does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

## `DependsOnTarget`

Let's assume that you have two tasks:

1. Build Project
2. Copy all content.

You can start your build by executing task 2 and then in the task declaration define its dependencies. So if you define that task 2 depends on task 1, the build process will start and execute task 1 and then 2.

## `AfterTargets`

Much simpler: it means only tasks which are execute after other targets. So taking the example from above - after Task 1 - build project execute task 2.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**There are two mainly differences:**

- First: Targets specified in the dependsOnTargets attribute are
  executed before those in AfterTargets.
- Second: If one of the targets specified in AfterTargets attribute got executed 
  this target get also executed after(I mean the target
  where you specify the AfterTargets attribute), which is not true for
  those in DependsOnTargets.

Answer (score 0):

They are converses of each other.

`DependsOnTargets` affects the behavior of the current task without affecting the behavior of the referenced task.

`AfterTargets` affects the behavior of the referenced task without affecting the behavior of the current task.

For example, if you have the following targets:

```
<Target Name="A" DependsOnTargets="B" />
<Target Name="B" />
<Target Name="C" AfterTargets="B" />
```

Then you get the following execution orders:

| Executed Target | Execution Order |
| --- | --- |
| A | B -> C -> A |
| B | B -> C |
| C | C |