# AfterTarget not fired in AfterBuild

Tags: msbuild

In my project I want to run an ILMerge target after the AfterBuild, so I did the following:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" AfterTargets="ILMerge" >
     <Message Importance="High" Text="AfterBuild"></Message>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="ILMerge">
   <Message Text="IlMerging" Importance="High" />
  </Target>
```

but the "IlMerging" text is not displayed, meaning that the AfterTargets in the AfterBuild is not being fired.

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to run the `ILMerge` target AFTER the `AfterBuild` target this is how you should write the script.

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" >
     <Message Importance="High" Text="AfterBuild"></Message>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="ILMerge" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
   <Message Text="IlMerging" Importance="High" />
  </Target>
```

Output:

```
AfterBuild: AfterBuild

ILMerge: ILMerge
```

If the Target AfterBuild should be ran after the ILMerge target then you need to change the AfterBuild target to what KMoraz suggested.

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="ILMerge" >
     <Message Importance="High" Text="AfterBuild"></Message>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="ILMerge" >
   <Message Text="IlMerging" Importance="High" />
  </Target>
```

Output:

```
ILMerge: ILMerge

AfterBuild: AfterBuild
```

Both scripts used the command line

msbuild testtarget.xml /t:AfterBuild

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I was making the wrong assumption with AfterTarget. I thought i had to put it in the AfterBuild target, like telling him: "When you are ready start the ILMerge target"

Answer (score 2):

See [What is the difference between 'DependsOnTargets' and 'AfterTargets'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2856018/147211)

In your case use `DependsOnTargets` since your target doesn't define a `BeforeTargets` for the execution chain to work.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="ILMerge" >
```