# BeforeTargets behaviour with conditional targets

Tags: .net, msbuild

Help me understand, why **target A (and D) is run** while **target B is not** when MSBuild is invoked like this:

```
msbuild /target:C
```

on this simple project (XML header omitted):

```
<Target Name="A" BeforeTargets="C">
  <Message Text="Inside target A" />
</Target>

<Target Name="B">
  <Message Text="Inside target B" />
</Target>

<Target Name="C" DependsOnTargets="B" Condition="'False'">
  <Message Text="Inside target C" />
</Target>

<Target Name="D" AfterTargets="C">
  <Message Text="Inside target D" />
</Target>
```

According to [target build order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order):

> - The `Condition` attribute of the target is evaluated. If the `Condition` attribute is present and evaluates to `false`, the target isn't executed and has no further effect on the build.
> - Before a target is executed, its `DependsOnTargets` targets are run.
> - Before a target is executed, any target that lists it in a `BeforeTargets` attribute is run.
> - ...
> - After a target is executed or skipped, any target that lists it in an `AfterTargets` attribute is run.

which is why it is only logical to conclude that since predicate *Before a target is executed* is the same for both `DependsOnTargets` and `BeforeTargets` attributes, **either both `A` and `B` should be run, or neither**.

As far as my understanding goes, neither `A` nor `B` should be run since MSBuild is asked to run target `C`, which is conditional and `Condition` evaluates to `false`.

---

**P.S.** MSBuild 15.5.180.51428

Comment: Why did you tag with MSBuild 4.0 when you explicitly say you are using MSBuild 15.5? Same with your answer.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Because attributes in question are features of MSBuild 4.0 and I thought that it was relevant.

Comment: So you think that the code hasn't changed at all between MSBuild 4.0 and 15.5 which is over 7 years newer?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Not since the 2009, it didn't. This issue is somewhat covered in second edition of "Inside The Microsoft Build Engine" which was released in 2009. I referenced current version of MSBuild to indicate that this is still a case in latest shipped version of MSBuild.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a case of peculiar difference between MSBuild 4.0 `BeforeTargets`, `AfterTargets` attributes versus older `DependsOnTargets` attribute.

### Short answer

`BeforeTargets` and `AfterTargets` are run regardless of the `Condition` whereas `DependsOnTargets` (and target itself) are skipped when `Condition` evaluates to `false`.

### Long answer

Investigation of `TargetBuilder::ProcessTargetStack()` [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/91c86a746b312fce1aba31f8fb8540e949c11a01/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TargetBuilder.cs#L394) showed that

1. Targets specified with `AfterTargets` and `BeforeTargets` attributes are [*unconditionally pushed*](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/91c86a746b312fce1aba31f8fb8540e949c11a01/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TargetBuilder.cs#L414) onto stack of targets to be built via `afterTargets` and `beforeTargets` lists returned by `GetTargetsWhichRunAfter()` and `GetTargetsWhichRunBefore()` methods.
2. Targets specified with `DependsOnTargets` attribute are [*pushed when non-null*](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/91c86a746b312fce1aba31f8fb8540e949c11a01/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TargetBuilder.cs#L444) onto stack of targets via `dependencies` list returned by `TargetEntry::GetDependencies()` method.
3. `Condition` attribute is actually evaluated only inside `TargetEntry::GetDependencies()` method which returns [*empty list when condition is present and resolves to* `false`](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/91c86a746b312fce1aba31f8fb8540e949c11a01/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TargetEntry.cs#L357), and list of dependencies otherwise.

Description in [target build order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order) seems to contradict the logic behind scheduling; the correct order seems to be:

> - Before a target is executed, any target that lists it in a `BeforeTargets` attribute is run.
> - The `Condition` attribute of the target is evaluated. If the `Condition` attribute is present and evaluates to `false`, the target and its `DependsOnTargets` targets are not executed.
> - ...
> - After a target is executed or skipped, any target that lists it in an `AfterTargets` attribute is run.

(Native speakers can probably document this better.)

**P.S.** Correct me if I'm wrong, but I come from C background and this [check](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/91c86a746b312fce1aba31f8fb8540e949c11a01/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TargetBuilder.cs#L442)

```
if (null != dependencies)
```

seems redundant to me because `dependencies` variable is initialised as

```
dependencies = currentTargetEntry.GetDependencies(...)
```

and `GetDependencies` returns initialised instance of `List<..>` [regardless](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/91c86a746b312fce1aba31f8fb8540e949c11a01/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TargetEntry.cs#L405) of `condition`:

```
List<...> GetDependencies(...)
{
    bool condition = ConditionEvaluator.EvaluateCondition(...);
    if (!condition)
    {
        ...
        return new List<...>();
    }
    ...
    List<...> dependencyTargets = new List<...>();
    ...
    return dependencyTargets;
}
```