# Difficulty using <Import> to modularize a Visual Studio project file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I'm attempting to modularize a Visual Studio project file, but it's not working.  This is for Visual Studio 2008 with .Net 3.5.

Shown below, the first example works, but the second one does not. How can I make it work..?

I'm new to this topic and probably missing something. I first became aware of it while reading a 3rd-party [blog](http://chrisa.wordpress.com/2014/07/18/customising-your-build-process/), and then found it in the [documentation](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-the-same-target-in-multiple-project-files) too. I've googled for more help, but there's too much information for me to find a relevant answer.

The main project file:

```
  ...
  <!-- main project file -->
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />

  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="This is a message from the *.vbproj file."/> ... this works
  </Target>
</Project>
```

...but if `<Import>` is used, with the same `<Target>` and `<Message>` in the imported file, it doesn't work. MSBuild seems to process everything correctly, but nothing happens...

The main project file:

```
  ...
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\CustomBuildEvents.targets" /> ... new tag

  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="This is a message from the *.vbproj file."/> ... this still works
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The imported targets file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="Hello from the imported file." Importance ="high"/> ... doesn't work
  </Target>
</Project>
```

And the build output, with `Verbosity` set to `Diagnostic`:

```
### Halfway through the output, this is the only mention of the imported file. ###

None
    CustomBuildEvents.targets      ... custom file
    My Project\Application.myapp
    My Project\Settings.settings

### And then at the end, no mention of the imported file or its message. ###

Done building target "CoreBuild" in project "MsBuildCustomTargetTester.vbproj".
Target "AfterBuild" in file "C:\Visual Studio 2008\Solutions\MsBuildCustomTargetTester\MsBuildCustomTargetTester\MsBuildCustomTargetTester.vbproj":
  Task "Message"
    Hello from the *.vbproj file.      ... message from main file
  Done executing task "Message".
Done building target "AfterBuild" in project "MsBuildCustomTargetTester.vbproj".
Target "Build" in file "c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets":
  Building target "Build" completely.
  No input files were specified.
Done building target "Build" in project "MsBuildCustomTargetTester.vbproj".

Done building project "MsBuildCustomTargetTester.vbproj".

Project Performance Summary:
      109 ms  C:\Visual Studio 2008\Solutions\MsBuildCustomTargetTester\MsBuildCustomTargetTester\MsBuildCustomTargetTester.vbproj   1 calls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `AfterBuild` is that it can only be defined once. So if you import it and then later in the project file define it again, the last definition wins and becomes the only definition.

To solve this you need to use the more advanced way to register events. Given that you are using Visual Studio 2008 (WHY?!), you need to use the more advanced syntax for your custom targets files:

```
<Project>
    <!-- 
        Redefines the original build order, includes the standard targets and 
        adds your new custom target to the end of the list.
    -->
    <PropertyGroup>
        <BuildDependsOn>
            $(BuildDependsOn);
            CustomTarget
        </BuildDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <CustomTarget> 
        <!-- Imported after Build -->
        <Message Text="Hello from the imported file." Importance ="high"/>
    </CustomTarget>
</Project>
```

There are other ways to do this which were introduced in MsBuild 4 with the  `BeforeTargets` and `AfterTargets` attributes on any target, but If I'm remembering correctly the above syntax should also work with the version of MsBuild that ships with Visual Studio 2008.

See also:

- [What is the difference between 'DependsOnTargets' and 'AfterTargets'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855713/what-is-the-difference-between-dependsontargets-and-aftertargets)
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2006/02/10/how-to-add-custom-process-at-specific-points-during-build-method-2/

Comment: Yes, I just read about the "only once" issue elsewhere and realized its importance. I'm using 2008 because it was surplus at work and I got it for free, license and all. Regarding your links, I already read the first one, sort of...it's a bit over my head for now. But the second one was helpful, and with your help it got me through this. The bit with  `<BuildDependsOn>` worked. Although the XML parser sneezed at me until I wrapped it in `<PropertyGroup>`. Along the way through this I did wonder if the `Target` name was an issue. Thanks for your help. +1 Now...on to the registry tasks, lol.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition is free for personal use, even if you build commercial software with it.

Comment: What's missing..? =-)

Comment: It's basically the same as Pro https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/ This is the limitation: Not for Enterprise organizations, defined as >250 PCs or > $1 Million US Dollars in annual revenue.

Comment: Wow, I'm doing my best Chloe Side-Eyes. Seems like there must be a catch somewhere, like Microsoft owns the code you make with it, kind of like Facebook owns any photos that you upload. I'm skeptical. =-)

Comment: Nah. It's just cool. Visual Studio Code is basically completely free and it comes with C# support too...Visual Studio  Community Edition has only the enterprise limitation on it.